# Does anyone have a configuration work around for PhpStorm to have xml php files?

Tags: phpstorm

There is a conflict between `<?xml` and php short tags.  So my configuration of PhpStorm keeps turning OutputXML.blade.php from `<?xml` to `<? xml` (spacing things out and creating invalid XML) so my XML output can not be parsed.

I've been searching thru the extensive PhpStorm config/prefs but I can't seem to find anything that helps.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2059 I guess (coming from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22668). Not sure on solution/workaround. Probably none ATM AFAIK.